# Join datatables in a dataset into a single table

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, axapta

Im trying to join multiple datatables to a single datatable.

```
var response = await client.ExecuteStaticQueryAsync(new ExecuteStaticQueryRequest() {
    queryName = "CustTableListPage"
});

var dataset = response.ExecuteStaticQueryResult.ToDataSet();
```

This gives me a dataset with 13 tables defined with relationships. Is it possible to join the tables into a single datatable using the existing relations?

I have tried the Merge() method, but this method seems to union the rows and creates a table with 9000 rows. The parent table has 1401 rows so the resulting table should also have 1401 rows.

What i tried:

```
var datatable = new DataTable("MergedCustTable");

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    datatable.Merge(dataset.Tables[i]);
```

Here i tried to merge the first and second table. The first table is the parent. This results with a datatable with 2802 rows.

Comment: Are you sure that the foreign keys are set properly? Then the Merge method should take it into account. But of course you need to use Merge with all 13 tables. However, you should show your approach.

Comment: I edited my question with my approach. The relations seem to be setup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has not been properly tested, but works on my dataset

```
public static class Extensions{
    public static DataTable Join(this DataTable table) {
        var columns = table.GetJoinedColumns();
        var newDt = new DataTable();
        newDt.Columns.AddRange(columns);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
            var newRow = newDt.NewRow();
            ProcessRows(row, newRow);
            newDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        return newDt;
    }

    private static DataColumn[] GetJoinedColumns(this DataTable table) {
        List<DataColumn> dataColumns = new List<DataColumn>();

        //Add columns from parent table
        foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
            dataColumns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.Table.TableName + "_" + dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType));

        //Add columns from from child tables
        foreach (DataRelation relation in table.ChildRelations)
            dataColumns.AddRange(GetJoinedColumns(relation.ChildTable));

        return dataColumns.ToArray();
    }

    private static void ProcessRows(DataRow currentRow, DataRow newRow) {
        //Add values from current row
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.ItemArray.Length; i++) {
            string columnName = currentRow.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            string tableName = currentRow.Table.TableName;
            newRow[tableName + "_" + columnName] = currentRow.ItemArray[i];
        }

        //Add values from child rows
        foreach (DataRelation relation in currentRow.Table.ChildRelations) {
            var childRows = currentRow.GetChildRows(relation);
            foreach (DataRow childRow in childRows) 
                ProcessRows(childRow, newRow);
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var dataset = response.ExecuteStaticQueryResult.ToDataSet();
var custTable = dataset.Tables[0];
DataTable dt = custTable.Join();
```